# How to update frame of tableView and hide segment control when search is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

In my VC, i have a search bar, segment control and tableView. I want the segment control to be hidden when clicked on searchbar and the tableView's frame to be updated so that the top constraint conforms to 0 search bar instead of segment control, segment control is right below the search bar. Here's a screenshot.

[image]

[image]

At the moment i have added search bar and segment control in storyboard but if there's a more easier and comprehensive approach via code then i'd be glad to use that.

Comment: Share the screenshot of applied constraints as well please.

Answer (score 0):

Take the outlet of height constraint of segment and set it to 0 for search field's editing mode and default size (say, 50px) for finish editing.

Answer (score 0):

Create outlet for button like acction, and try this code:

```
 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I hope, i help you.